# Peano's Axiom: Is it implied that successor of a number is not the number itself?

Tags: peano-axioms

Using the Peano's Axioms from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html) as the basis, I'm wondering if it is implied that the successor of a number is not the number itself, or is it deducible?

Comment: It is possible to deduce it, using the fact that $0$ is not a successor, and using the induction axiom

Comment: *Hint*: assume that for some $z: S(z)=z$. Applying induction, let $n_0$ the *least* $z$ such that ... and assume that $n_0 \ne 0$ (otherwise: $S(0)=0$ contradicting Peano Ax.1). Thus, $S(n_0)=n_0=S(n_0-1)$; by Ax.2: $n_0=n_0-1$ and thus $S(n_0-1)=n_0-1$, contradicting the "minimality" of $n_0$.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA : Not sure how $S(0)=0$ is a contradiction. Are you referring to '0 is a natural number' for Ax.1 ?

Comment: @KGhatak: Writing $0$ as the successor of $0$ contradicts the axiom that $0$ is not a successor of any number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow I missed it..

Comment: Ax.3: $\forall x \ (S(x) \ne 0)$ and thus also $S(0) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can formalize these [Peano's Axioms in first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) as follows:

$\forall x \ s(x) \not = 0$ (this is Peano axiom 3)

$\forall x \ \forall y \ (s(x) = s(y) \rightarrow x = y)$ (this is Peano Axiom 4)

for any formula $\varphi(x)$:

$(\varphi(0) \land \forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(s(x)))) \rightarrow \forall x \ \varphi(x)$  (this is a general scheme that captures Peano Axiom 5 ... $S$ would be the set of all objects for which $\varphi(x)$ is true)

Using this, you can derive the statement $\forall x \ s(x) \not = x$, i.e. that the successor of any number is never that number itself:

[image]

Comment: What software did you use there?

Comment: @cdwe It's called Fitch. It comes with the textbook Language, Proof, and Logic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!