# Proving that no number is the successor of itself

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

I'm doing my research project on Peano Arithmetic, and need to show the PA can prove that no number is the successor of itself.

I've seen an answer here: [Peano's Axiom: Is it implied that successor of a number is not the number itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361374/peanos-axiom-is-it-implied-that-successor-of-a-number-is-not-the-number-itself), but I'm struggling to understand from line 5 - why is it introduced? And why is line 6 introduced?

Thanks in advance for your help

Dani

Comment: Looks like a proof by induction where you show that the property $s(x)\neq x$ is true for all $x$. Line 5 would be your induction hypothesis, or whatever it is called in English. Edit: It seems it is called the "inductive hypothesis".

Comment: Are you familiar with mathematical induction?

Comment: @DanielV - yes I am. You prove something for the base case (in this case '0') and the for all number up to 'n'; if you can prove for 'n + 1' you can prove for all 'n'...?

Comment: @N.Bach - thank you. That helps a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer that, it must be seen what lines # and fou say.

**Line 3:** If $s(0)\neq0$ and if, for every natural $n$, $s(n)\neq n\implies s\bigl(s(n)\bigr)\neq s(n)$, then, for every $n$, $s(n)\neq n$.

This is just the induction principle applied to the proposition $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):s(n)\neq n$.

**Line 4:** $s(0)\neq 0$

This is here to assert that the base case of induction holds.

Then lines 5 to 10 are here to prove that if $s(n)\neq n$, then $s\bigl(s(n)\bigr)\neq s(n)$, that is, in order to comple that induction proof. So, he starts by picking an $a\in\mathbb N$ and he assumes that $s(a)\neq a$. In order to prove that $s\bigl(s(a)\bigr)\neq s(a)$, he assumes that they are equal and reaches a contradiction. Since such a contradiction is reached, $s\bigl(s(a)\bigr)$ is indeed different form $s(a)$ and the theorem is proved.

Comment: thank you. It makes more sense now. When he says in line 5: s(a) not equal to a, that is an assumption? Then it makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: @Dani Yes, that is an assumption. He assumes that $s(a)\neq a$ and he deduces from this that $s\bigl(s(a)\bigr)\neq s(a)$.